# Webpacker fails to compile within Dockerized Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, webpack

So I'm working on dockerizing a rails application that's utilizing webpacker. I'm able to get the application to load except webpacker fails to compile.

Versions

- ruby 2.4.2
- rails 5.2.2
- webpacker 4.0.7 (pulled from Gemfile.lock)
- Docker 19.03.5
- npm 6.11.3
- node 12.6.0

config/webpack is present and development, production, and test all have:

```
const environment = require('./environment');
module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig();
```

environment.js has:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
module.exports = environment
```

webpacker.yml has:

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: false

  resolved_paths: ['app/assets']

  cache_manifest: false

  extract_css: true

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  check_yarn_integrity: true

  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    inline: true    
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default
  compile: false
  extract_css: true
  cache_manifest: true
```

So to Dockerize I did the following:

- updated my config/environments development of config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity to false
- Updated config/database.yml under default to have host:db and username: postgres
- Added a Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, .ssh folder, and scripts/docker-entry.sh (all below)

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.4.2
RUN printf "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  build-essential \
  postgresql-client \
  nodejs
ADD .ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" > /root/.ssh/config
WORKDIR /app
COPY lib/ ./lib
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5
COPY . .
RUN rm /root/.ssh/id_rsa
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]
CMD ["rails", "server", "-p", "3000", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    entrypoint: ['./scripts/docker-entry.sh']
    command: rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - app-deps:/app/vendor
  db:
    image: postgres:10.3
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  app-deps:
  pgdata:
```

In my scrips/docker-entry.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm /app/tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

bundle install

bundle exec rake db:migrate 2>/dev/null || bundle exec rake db:setup

exec bundle exec "$@"
```

I through in the Dockerfile under run the yarn \ thinking that might have been the issue but really it was a last ditch effort. When I do a docker-compose build  I have no issues.

When I do docker-compose up no issues. However when I load a page:

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/runner.rb:13:in ``': No such file or directory - yarn (Errno::ENOENT)
```

So I'm guessing I wasn't included webpacker in the Docker so I updated the docker-compose.yml to include:

```
  webpacker:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    command: ./bin/webpack-dev-server
    volumes:
      - .:/webpacker-app
    ports:
      - '3035:3035'
```

Then updated config/webpacker.yml for dev_server to use host: webpacker

Updated my env with:

```
NODE_ENV=development
RAILS_ENV=development
WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

Then updated my Dockerfile with:

```
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash \
  && apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
  && apt-get update && apt-get install -y yarn && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I then did a docker-compose build with no issues and I see name_app_1, name_webpacker_1, name_db_1. Then docker-compose up has issues.

```
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 8.x
```

I've also tried adding into my Dockerfile RUN yarn --pure-lockfile and then in my docker-compose.yml under app > volumes - /app/node_modules/ in hopes of handling the issues with node.

This resulted in the same error. I then thought it was likely just an issue with the OS so I added a dockerignore file and added in node_modules. And updated my Dockerfile to have:

```
ADD package.json .
RUN mkdir -p node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-51
RUN curl -L https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.0/linux-x64-51_binding.node -o node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-51/binding.node

RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild node-sass
ADD . .
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

No issues with the build but when I run docker-compose up:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find styles/application in /app/public/packs/manifest.json
```

I'm at a loss. Did I forget to add something to my docker-compose? Is my Dockerfile wrong?

Comment: Try using the latest LTS node—currently node 12.x.

Comment: node is at 12.6.0. I'll add the npm version info

Comment: Interesting. This message seems to indicate your enviroment is on node 8.x: `Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 8.x`